# heroku telebot has no attribute

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, heroku

Попытался развернуть телеграм бот на хероку, но после деплоя в логе вылетает ошибка(стоит упомянуть что этот же скрипт без изменений спокойно работает в ручном режиме на пк)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем понимании это из-за каких-то проблем с pyTelegramBotApi - но в requirements и он и telebot добавлены.
Раньше была похожая проблема но еще до развертывания - тоже не находило модуль, решилось все ручной установкой pyTelegramBotApi.

Еще посещали мысли что ошибки какие-то в виртуальном окружении, так как создавал это все в PyCharm'е, но создание нового окружения вручную не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на этот вопрос не впечатлил меня, дело было как раз в requirements.txt и как раз в тех двух библиотеках.

Чтобы все заработало нужно просто поменять их местами. Было:

```
pyTelegramBotAPI==3.7.3

telebot==0.0.3
```

Стало:

```
telebot==0.0.3


pyTelegramBotAPI==3.7.3
```

**В итоге порядок их закачки в хероку будет иным, и проблема решится сама собой**